# setInterval variable will not stop in socket.io web game

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, timer, socket.io

In some cases the function below will not call clearInterval even though the question timer goes lower than 0.  My console reports 0..-1..-2..etc. and even though it meets the condition it does not stop the timer.  This is using socket.io so I'm not sure if it's some sort of timing issue because it seems to happen randomly.

EDIT: So this code is inside a function the function is called from two different places.  The var questionTimer is declared globally in my app.js file because I use it in another function.  If questionBeginCountdown is called again before clearInterval is called would that mean there are two separate instances of setInterval running (ie. the first instance of setInterval calls clearInterval but because the returned value for questionTimer is different it fails)?

```
function questionBeginCountdown()
{ 
questionTimer = setInterval(function() {
          questionTimerCount--;
          playerSpc.emit('update interval', questionTimerCount);
          gameSpc.emit('update interval', questionTimerCount);
          guestHost.emit('update interval', questionTimerCount);
          console.log('timer count: ' + questionTimerCount);
          if (questionTimerCount <= 0) {
                console.log('stopping timer.');
                clearInterval(questionTimer);
                questionTimesUp(); //calls a function that emits various things
            }
        }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I couldn't recreate the error using the code you supplied. Maybe one of your other methods is recreating the setInterval?

Comment: There's not enough information here to tell, but the most common cause is that you're starting the interval multiple times but storing the references to only one variable.

Comment: @JJJ this is what I thought was the case.  Maybe I'm not understanding how javascript creates a reference to a variable. 

I have questionTimer created as a global because I make a reference to it from another function.  I will add an edit to show better what's going on with my code.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain I updated my question to better show what's going on.

Comment: You show a LOT of variables that have no local declaration with `var` or `let` or `const`.  That means they are either explicitly declared in a higher scope or they are (yuk, yuk, yuk) implicit globals.  In either case, each time you call `questionBeginCountdown()`, you will overwrite the previous values of these variables, thus making it impossible to ever stop the previous interval (since you overwrite the timer handle you need to pass to `clearInterval()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If questionBeginCountdown is called again before clearInterval is called would that mean there are two separate instances of setInterval running?

I believe it does. Maybe rethink why you're calling it twice to begin with.

One quick fix is to, inside questionBeginCountdown check if questionTimer is already set before setting the interval. Then somewhere down the line when the timer is done and after clearing the interval, set questionTimer to null.

Another quick fix, if you need two timers independent of each other, is to make questionTimerCount local to the questionBeginCountdown, but that depends on what you're doing with the timer.

**Edit**

An example of what I said about.

```js
let questionTimer,
    questionTimerCount = 2;
function questionBeginCountdown()
{ 
  if (questionTimer)
    return
    
  questionTimer = setInterval(function() {
            questionTimerCount--;
            //playerSpc.emit('update interval', questionTimerCount);
            //gameSpc.emit('update interval', questionTimerCount);
           // guestHost.emit('update interval', questionTimerCount);
            console.log('timer count: ' + questionTimerCount);
            if (questionTimerCount <= 0) {
                  console.log('stopping timer.');
                  clearInterval(questionTimer);
                  //questionTimesUp();
                  questionTimer = null;
              }
          }, 1000);
}

// calling it 4 times doesn't set 4 intervals
questionBeginCountdown();
questionBeginCountdown();
questionBeginCountdown();
questionBeginCountdown();
```

Comment: Thanks I will do this!